# Feasibility of using ionic liquid fuels in an MHD type reactor

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ionic-compounds, conductivity, fuel

First off I would like to say that my knowledge on chemistry, even general chemistry, is basic if not poor.

That said, I have some intuituions on this matter. I haven´t found any paper regarding this kind of system, and that is pretty much a killer for me. 
Even with that I´d still like to ask the question.

Ionic liquids, liquid salts, are regarded as having some conductive capacities, being low to moderate conductors due to their ionic nature. 
I know that salts have been used in MHD (magnetohydrodynamic) systems due to their high melting points -the ionic bond being particularly strong- and their conductive potential.

I have an specific fuel reaction in mind, An hydrazinium based propellant + LOX (liquid oxygen) as oxidizer,

[HO-C2H4-N2H4]+[NO3]- + 2.25 O2 = 2 CO2 + 1.5 N2 + 4.5 H2O

for example. 
I read that ionic liquid salts do not need to be dissolved for the anion and the cation to conduct electricity (https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_is_the_electrical_conductivity_of_ionic_liquids_in_comparison_with_metals)
Outside of that I´d like to know if hydrainium based reactions do have some electric potential, or if by any reason wich I did not manage to grasp, it is simply out of the question to use them in such machines.

I would be very pleased to know if something is just worng or has been misunderstood.

Source for the reaction: http://cdn.intechweb.org/pdfs/20222.pdf, page 9 (455 in the original text).

Overal description of how a MHD machine works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_generator

*Edit: 
The majority of the volume is occupied by the reaction products. Using just conventional fuels like liquid hydrogen is just more practical.

Still, we could use a thermal/catalytical decomposition reaction, like 6 NH3OHNO3(aq) = 2 N2(g) + 2 NH4NO3(s or l) + 6 H2O(g) + 4 HNO3(g), where both a salt and water are produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fuel is oxidized at high temperature, the conductivity of the fuel itself is irrelevant -- only the **conductivity of the combustion products**, which are ionized because of the high temperature and are therefor conductive. [Brittanica states](https://www.britannica.com/technology/magnetohydrodynamic-power-generator/Major-types-of-MHD-systems) that temperatures greater than ~2,500 K are needed for sufficient ionization. Alkali metals can be used to increase ionization, or [higher temperatures have been used with inert gases.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/893319)

Note that the temperature of ions and electrons in the gas are *not* necessarily the same, due to the difference in mass and time to reach equilibrium. This impacts on conductivity and the rate of erosion of the MHD components.